# Ansible is not accepting customer fail module

Tags: ansible, devops

```
- name:                             "Waiting for URL to come up."
  uri:
    url:                            "{{ url }}/libs/granite/core/content/login.html"
    status_code:                    200
  register:                         result
  until:                            result.status == 200
  retries:                          10
  delay:                            10
  fail:
    msg: "Service was not available after 10 minutes. Files were installed except for the ones that required AEM to be available"
```

I'm adding the fail message so when the task fails we will have a meaningful output.
However I receive an error:

```
 line 3, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name:                             \"Waiting for URL to come up.\"\n  ^ here\n"}[0
```

I checked at the documentation and it seems that is the right way to do. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation for the `uri` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/uri_module.html), you will
note that there is no `fail` parameter. There is, however, a separate
[`fail` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/fail_module.html). If you'd like to use that, you will need to
rewrite your `uri` task such that it does not cause Ansible fail, but
instead records the task result so that you can use it in a subsequent
`fail` action.

```
- name:                             "Waiting for URL to come up."
  uri:
    url:                            "{{ url }}/libs/granite/core/content/login.html"
    status_code:                    200
  until:                            result.status == 200
  retries:                          10
  delay:                            10
  register: uri_result
  ignore_errors: true

- name: fail with custom message
  when: uri_result is failed
  fail:
    msg: >-
      Service was not available after 10 minutes. Files
      were installed except for the ones that required AEM
      to be available.
```

Comment: Can you have "register" written twice like you did?

Comment: No, you can't. I hadn't noticed the earlier one :). Let me fix that.

Comment: Just a question in this case you use uri_result is failed. IF I want to use the same condition in other tasks after. Can I just use result.status == 200. Else how would u define if successfull? For example : aem == "something and uri_result == ??

Comment: You can certainly check `result.status` if you prefer. You can test for a successful task by checking `uri_result is success`.

Comment: Great tips! I also saw  "is not failed". That I added. Should work the same as "is success" right?

Comment: `is not failed` would catch things with a task result of `changed`, `success`, or `skipped`. See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-task-results for details.